# Incubus - Stellar, where is "1"?

Tags: rhythm, analysis

I was discussing this track with a fellow drummer.  From the first verse, we get a typical backbeat, so it seems obvious where 1 is.  But, he argued that the snare is actually on 1 and 3-

If the snare is on 1 and 3 in the Verse, then the Prechorus timing makes more sense (I attribute this to the snare being on 3, thus making it a typical halftime backbeat).

If the snare is on 1 and 3 in the Chorus, then there is no time signature change needed at the beginning or end of the bridge.  If the snare is on 2 and 4, then we need 2 time signature changes (or, the snare in the bridge is on 2, and 1 is a weak beat, which makes no sense).

Also, I noticed that if the snare is on 1 and 3 in the Chorus, then the first note of the guitar riff is "1", without any pickup notes.  Listening to the guitar in isolation, the "1 and 3" interpretation seems more appealing.

The bassist in [this live performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfxgJ5AL67s) also grooves to the music by bobbing and "landing" on the snare hits in the verse- indicating this is 1 and 3- and grooves the same way in the bridge, "landing" on what seems more clearly to be 1 and 3.

[This sheet music for sale puts the snare on 2 and 4.](https://www.musicnotes.com/sheetmusic/mtd.asp?ppn=MN0115145)  [This one too.](https://www.sheetmusicnow.com/products/stellar-p382069)  I don't know who wrote it out, though.

Of course, there is also an obvious third interpretation- The snare is on 2 and 4 in the verse and chorus, 3 in the prechorus, 3 in the bridge, and we sprinkle in time signature changes as needed to make everything line up.

**Where is the downbeat intended to be here, and how would a professional musician in this genre likely interpret the rhythm here?**

Comment: A 1&3 backbeat is not that unusual, especially with side stick. The first guitar note is on “1” and the first word, “meet” is on beat 2.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I disagree, but the fact that it does sound like that is the source of the question, I think. The vocal "meet" is beat 1. It sounds a little wonky until everything establishes itself after the drum entry. With "meet" on 1, that places the chorus's "it" ("How do you do it?") on 1.

Comment: "Meet" is on two. See below.

Comment: @Tetsujin "Meet" on two is inconsistent with the rest of the song.

Comment: @Aaron - it absolutely isn't. Read my entire analysis below. No sig changes required, everything just falls into place. Bang on the desk in 4's if you need to, to start with. I've even found a couple of comparison songs with similar elements. It really is one of those clap your hand over your face once you grok it songs.

Comment: @Tetsujin I spent a fair amount of time conducting the piece — banging on the desk, as you say. I stand by my analysis.

Comment: @Aaron - I stand by mine, no sig changes, reduction is by far the simplest method. It's just a 'groove' it's not higher maths. I started with it the wrong way up & it demanded mental hoop-jumping. By halfway I turned it over & all the hoops just vanished with it.

Comment: @Aaron To me the most obvious downbeat aside from the first low A on the guitar is the second syllable of “again” at the end of the verse. That works out perfectly in 4/4 with the guitar’s first low A on 1. “It” is not a downbeat,, the words “do” and “it” are 8th note upbeats on 4+ and 1+. The bass and bass drum are playing “Roxanne”, 1+ and 2. They even quote the name “Roxanne” several times in the song.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - ah, well spotted. I hadn't listened to the lyrics. I'd arrived at Roxanne independently, just off the groove itself.

Comment: It's interesting how many ways you can hear this song. To me it sounds like the basic pulse is very slow and the snare lands on 1, 2, 3 and 4 except the part between 2:10 and 2:40 where it's 2 and 4.

Comment: @ojs Great point, I considered that as well and it’s a valid interpretation, especially at 2:10 when it’s a slow 2&4 backbeat groove. The “Roxanne” vibe early on makes me think in the faster quarters for at least that part of the song with a half time feel at 2:10.

Comment: In the verse I definitely hear the snare on 1 and 3.  The rest of the instruments don't make sense otherwise.  It seems more ambiguous in the chorus, which I think is done on purpose, but I still hear the snare on 1 and 3.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not hearing any time signature change at all. Sure, emphasis could be considered slightly odd, even intentionally off-putting, but it never breaks the 4/4.

I always consider this type of ambiguous track to actually be organised by the 'simplest is usually the most likely' principle. Don't change time signature if you don't have to. The fewer hoops to jump the easier it is to keep straight in your head. Then, once you get the hang of it, it will never confuse you again.

The beep beep - for which I'm almost certain they will have had to thank (& pay) the [Supremes, Reflections](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV72YrB1454)<sup>[1]</sup> - seems to be a tick short [if you count it you get 15 & the guitar kind of lags in. It's not a clean sig change, so I'd ignore it], but after that the guitar riff starts on the one. The opening lyric, "Meet" is on two. The hats come in on one, meaning the kick opens on `& 2`. The bass follows this kick in a one-drop style. The first snare is on 3.
That then puts the snare mainly on the 1 & 3 right through. If you follow this, then all the changes happen on the one.
The cleanest places to hear this is at the large drops at approx 1 minute & 2 minutes.

I didn't listen to the live version until after I'd finished this answer. It's far less ambiguous than the studio version, once they're all in a room playing it together.

The bass line in the verses is vaguely reminiscent of Roxanne *[and I've subsequently discovered they actually say Roxanne in the lyrics a couple of times, so this is likely not coincidental]*, borrowing from the reggae 'one-drop' style where the bass never hits the one. The guitar is playing on-beat rather than off, which emphasises this. The drums in contrast are a relatively straight 2 & 4 backbeat, though Copeland is never ordinary.

The snare pattern in your example, though, reminds me of Kings of Leon, Charmer. To get you into the count… bass starts right on the one, simple as it gets. Don't let the drums throw you with the pushes. Snare is on-beat almost all the way through. If you lose it, you have to start over or wait for the drop section in the middle, where it reverts for a while to regular 2 & 4 ;)

There's another track, famous for its ambiguous 'one'. David Byrne heard it one way round, Brian Eno the other. They compromised by making the verses and choruses switch emphasis so each got their own way in half the song. You can either count a 2-beat bar in & out of the choruses, or just relax & let it flow. Both are 'right'. The bass line could also be considered to be an extension of the Roxanne line, but playing through the one, ending the same on the two. [e 1 & 2].

<sup>[1]</sup> I checked and [WhoSampled.com](https://www.whosampled.com/Incubus/Stellar/) agrees with me

Comment: It seems like this is a clear winner for common opinion here.  I will say that I originally heard it with snare on 2 and 4 because that's such a common thing in pop and rock music that it's hard to override that signal once it's really ingrained into your mind.  All the other "hoops" were little things compared to hearing the snare on 1.  In fact, I found this music for sale, and they put the snare on 2.  I should add that to the original question.  I don't know who wrote that sheet, though.

Comment: The drummer mentioned in the question agrees that the snare is in 1 and 3, but admits that he has trouble hearing it that way, and sometimes reverts back to the "2 and 4" interpretation.

Comment: It was the realisation it was similar to Roxanne that locked me into the final interpretation.  Once I had that, I could sit in the groove.

Answer (score -1):

**Kick drum and bass land on the 1, standard 2 & 4 backbeat.**

If one starts listening from about 0:16, the 4/4 beat is clear and consistent until 2:08. At about 2:08, there is a single 3/4 bar along with the lyrics "like I do". Then the song is back in the standard 4/4 until 2:36. At that point there are nine beats leading back into 4/4, which continues until the end.

The opening is a little harder to pick up. When the main vocals being at 0:06 ("Meet me..."), that's the downbeat. Once that's established, the 4/4 continues, but is clearest once the drums enter at 0:18. It helps to count the first "beep" at 0:04 as "4", which puts the first bass entry also on "4" and the vocal entry on "1".

**Regarding interpretation.** The bands I've played in would interpret it as above: everything is 4/4 except for a single 3/4 bar (or maybe a 7/4 bar) and a single 9/4 bar. It's not uncommon for songwriters to add or drop a beat or a bar here and there.

Comment: I don't hear a single time change right the way through.